# Feasibility of this plasma cannon-Round 2

Tags: science-based, internal-consistency, weapons, electromagnetism

My intention is to develop this idea through multiple phases of flaw searching, proposing possible solutions and starting it over again, until there are little to no flaws remain.

[the first phase of this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/71995/quick-question-the-feasability-of-this-plasma-cannon)

---

**Flaw searching round 1 Conclusion:**

- ***The target is locked to me and I'm locked to him with magnetic fields, so it has a chance to become a tug of war scenario.***

**Possible Solution:** Hillarious and original, I keep it.

---

---

- ***There are more energy efficient ways.***

**Possible solution:** I'm perfectly aware of that and the fact that this weapon wouldn't be energy efficient, but sometimes, having a beam that can cut through steel like if it was made out of butter, is good for [dispatching multiple foes with one, quick strike](https://youtu.be/mdU8dyjgXU0?t=96).

- ***How would I make sure that the plasma doesn't cool down quickly?***

**Possible solution:** This is still an important issue, my idea was to circulate electricity, through the plasma to keep it from cooling.

- ***The plasma is hot enough to melt down the face of the user with its radiant heat.***

**Possible solution:** This isn't really an issue if the user is inside a mecha that designed to withstand the power of its own weapon, also tokamaks use magnetic fields to prevent similar things from happening.

- ***The change of a magnetic field induces currents in conductors nearby.***

**Possible solution:** Just like in the previous one, this can be [solved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage) relatively easily.

- ***Strong magnetic fields give away my presence and there are mines that explode when nearby a magnetic field.***

**Possible solution:** [Easy cake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnet) and there is a way to [protect](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/12527/32097) the cannon from mines and kinetic force.

---

These solutions are mine and are likely to be flawed. **So if I did, then where I'd failed?**

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a lightsaber.

Comment: This question already has some "unclear what you're asking" votes on it.

Comment: @Molot I made some clarifications, is that sufficient?

Comment: We'll see. For me good enough.

Comment: @Mołot So? Whats now?

Comment: 5 people voted to close, 5 people need to vote reopen. Seems that no one else voted to reopen. If you will edit it further, it'll get put back into reopen review queue. Or you can ask on http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/ what to do now.

Answer (score 1):

A plasma is composed of electrons and ions.  Each will take an independent path in a magnetic field. In general a plasma will follow the magnetic field, and won't cross field lines.

More detail:  A charged particle in a magnetic field experiences a force at right angles to both the direction of travel and the magnetic field.  The effect is that it circles the field lines.  Faster moving particle, bigger circle.

A dense plasma is one that the combination of particle velocity and particle density are sufficient that there are large numbers of collisions between particles.  This keeps the plasma at a fairly uniform temperature.  In addition a dense plasma will heat up and slow down when it hits a magnetic field. Motion in a single direction is randomized as heat.  (Electrons and ions spiral in opposite directions, making collisions more frequent.)  A sparse plasma will be be deflected into spiral paths along the field lines of the magnetic field.

A plasma is a very hot gas, and by itself will expand rapidly.  Because it's charged, it can carry a current.  The right set of currents creates a magnetic field which contains the plasma and keeps it from expanding.  As the currents dissipate from resistance, the plasma expands.

Ball lighting may be a natural self contained plasma.

Comment: [yeah!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ball_lightning#Direct_measurements_of_natural_ball_lightning)

Comment: So what are you saying with this answer, exactly? (anyways, thanks for it, now I know more about the plasma)